# Return JSON with object model or JSON with parsed view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, view

I'm creating website with lots of AJAX logic. I started to wondering should I return JSON with object model (because I have to make some requests and then replace/insert some html nodes in response) like:

```
{ 'Author' : 'Name@Surname', 'Email': 'some@email', 'listOfSomething' = [...], ...} //very advanced JSON
```

and then use some js template engine to parse my object and insert in the right place in the DOM

OR

return JSON with parsed razor template so something like:

```
{listOfSomething: [{id:0, parsedView:ASP.NET.ParseViewWithModel(MyModel[0])},{id:1, parsedView:ASP.NET.ParseViewWithModel(MyModel[1])}, ... ]}
```

the pros of second choice is that it will require much less logic but. Which approach should be use and when? Is the second approach may be good solution?

Answer (score 1):

If what is being returned is only used in one place, then I would say option two is a good approach since you can tailor the HTML specifically for where it is going to be used and all you have to do is simply inject it into the DOM.

Otherwise, if what the AJAX returns is used in multiple places, then I would stick to returning JSON and let each client do what it needs with the raw data.

Also, if third-party developers are using it, then JSON is definitely the way to go.